# How could I jump number for variable?

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I have json with name like:

```
product_1
product_2
product_3
```

Could I have loop with variable + number?

My problem is: `json.subject__ + (i + 1)`

```
const json = items[0].json["data"];

var count = json.count;

var subject = [];
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  subject[i] = json.subject__ + (i + 1);
}
```

My json structure like this:

```
[
  {
    "data": {
      "use_for": "website",
      "product__1": "bai 1",
      "length__1: "option 1",
      "product__2": "bai 2",
      "length__2": "option 2",
      "product__3": "bai 3",
      "length__3": "option 3",
      "format__3": [
         "sss",
         "kkk", ...
```

Comment: please add your data structure.

Comment: I guess you want to do this: `json['subject__' + (i + 1)]` instead of this `json.subject__ + (i + 1)`.

Comment: btw, you should be push()'ing to an array, but you could simply use map() instead of a for loop

Comment: I added data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bracket notation for that:

```js
subject[i] = json["subject__" + (i + 1)];
```